# How onUserLocationChange() effect onRegionChange() in react native maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have developed a application using react native map. I would like to know does the **onRegionChange()** method is called by default whenever the **onUserLocationChange()** is trigger?

Answer (score 0):

After deeper search in the code source, the response is **NO**.

onRegionChange function called continuously when the region changes, such as when a user is dragging the map.